# ¿Cómo puedo listar (ListView) los videos que están en la SdCard?

Tags: android, listview, arrayadapter

Soy relativamente nueva trabajando en Android, me gustaría que me ayudasen.

He estado tratando de hacer un reproductor de video; los objetivos son: 
-Obtener los videos que están en la SdCard del dispositivo.
-Listarlos en un listView.
-Seleccionar el item del listview, es decir, el video y abrirlo (por ahora esta parte no la hago.

El problema es que, a pesar de que tengo videos guardados en la sd, la app no me los lista, como si no hubiese nada.

No sé qué error de lógica he de tener.

Gracias de antemano.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> videos;
VideoAdapter videoAdapter;

void readVideosSdCard(){
    videos = new ArrayList<>();
    String sd_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

    File file = new File (sd_path);
    String [] fileNames = file.list();

    if (fileNames != null){
        for (String s : fileNames){
            if (s.endsWith(".mp4")|| s.endsWith(".mkv")){
                 videos.add(s);
            }
        }
    }

}

void iniciarAdaptador (){
    videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_videos,videos);
    listView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView_id);
    readVideosSdCard();
    iniciarAdaptador();

}

AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String vname = videos.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clickeaste en: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
};
```

}`

**VideoAdapter.java:**

```
   Context context;
int resource;
ArrayList<String> videoList;

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = null;

    v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resource,parent,false);
    TextView txtVideoName = v.findViewById(R.id.video_name);
    String Vname = videoList.get(position);
    txtVideoName.setText(Vname);

    return v;
}

public VideoAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, ArrayList <String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    videoList = objects;
}
```

}

**list_videos.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:paddingTop ="20dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/videoview" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/video_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Video Name"
    android:textColor="#000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas manejando una version de Android mayor a Masmelo debes implementar este codigo:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
//ask for permission
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);}
```

Una vez el permiso sea aceptado intenta este codigo, a mi me funciono en una app de prueba.

```
String sd_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment."Directorio donde tengas los videos").getAbsolutePath();

    File directory = new File(sd_path);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    for (File f :files) {
        if (f.getName().endsWith(".mp4") || f.getName().endsWith(".mkv")){
            videos.add(f.getName());
        }
    }
```